# HSLF POI Apache Change font color of specific part of a TextRun

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using the POI Apache library, specifically, the HSLF part (to edit -2007 Powerpoints). I have a TextRun object and I would like to partially change its color. For instance, I have "Example B". I would like to have "Example" in red and "B" in blue. Is that possible?

Comment: Please add your code. [ask]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)